# SQL query with child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Parent and Child.

Parent table has following columns

Parent_id, Name

Child Table has following columns

Parent_id (foreign key), Identifier, identifier_value

Now I want to list different parent_id with names and identifier_value(of child table) having same identifier_value for Identifier = "test" but different identifier_value for Identifier = "test1"

i.e consider an example

Parent Table ---

```
Parent_id, Name
1, XYZ
2, PQR
```

Child Table

```
Parent_id, Identifier, Identifier_value
1, test, value1
1, test1, ghght 
2, test, value1
2, test1, khkhgj
```

output should be

```
1, XYZ, value1, ghght
2, PQR, value1, khkhgj
```

It should return result for the above example as in parent_id 1 and 2, test has same value but test1 has different value

This is what I have written till now

```
SELECT p.parent_id,
  p.name,
  eid.identifier_value,
  eid2.identifier_value
FROM parent p,
  child eid,
  child eid2
WHERE e.parent_id             = eid.parent_id
AND e.parent_id               = eid2.parent_id
AND eid.identifier  = 'test'
AND eid2.identifier = 'test1'
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM child eid3
  WHERE eid3.identifier = 'test'
  AND eid3.value                    =eid.value
  AND eid3.parent_id             <> eid.parent_id
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM child eid4
    WHERE eid4.parent_id         = eid3.parent_id
    AND eid4.identifier = 'test1'
    AND eid3.value                 <> eid4.value
    AND eid4.identifier = eid3.identifier
    )
  )
```

The issue in the last subquery. Need some advice on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select p.*, c1.Identifier_value, c2.Identifier_value
from parent p left join
     child c1
     on c1.parent_id = p.id and c1.identifier = 'test' left join
     child c2
     on c2.parent_id = p.id and c2.identifier = 'test2'
where c1.Identifier_value <> c2.Identifier_value;
```

Comment: No, identifier test should have same identifier_value and identifier test1 should have different identifier values . Request you to kindly re-read my question.

Comment: @Sunny . . . That is just a `where` clause.

Comment: Each parent has two identifiers test and test1. I want to list those parents having same identifier_value for test and different for test1. I hope that makes clear. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am afraid your query is giving me incorrect result. Can you please read my question, comments again and also see my query as I am sure I was very close with it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue with the query given by gordon, Below are the results for the sample data which you have provided.

```
with parent_table as
(
select 1 as parent_id, 'XYZ' as name from dual
union
select 2 as parent_id, 'PQR' as name from dual
),
child_table as 
(
select 1 as parent_id, 'test' as Identifier, 'value1' as Identifier_value from dual
union
select 1 as parent_id, 'test1' as Identifier, 'ghght' as Identifier_value from dual
union
select 2 as parent_id, 'test' as Identifier, 'value1' as Identifier_value from dual
union
select 2 as parent_id, 'test1' as Identifier, 'khkhgj' as Identifier_value from dual
)
select p.*, c1.Identifier_value, c2.Identifier_value
from parent_table p left join
     child_table c1
     on c1.parent_id = p.parent_id and c1.identifier = 'test' left join
     child_table c2
     on c2.parent_id = p.parent_id and c2.identifier = 'test1'
where c1.Identifier_value <> c2.Identifier_value;
```

Output same as expected output in the question.

```
1   XYZ value1  ghght
2   PQR value1  khkhgj
```

Comment: what is the relation between c1.identifier_value and c2.identifier_value in the last line. They are independent

Comment: In question you have mentioned *but different identifier_value for Identifier = "test1"..* to identify different identifier value for same  id we have that condition

Comment: yes that means for parentId 1 test1 should have different value but test should have the same value, do you get it now?

Comment: just see my query added in the question, you will come to know

Comment: you are comparing test identifier value with test1 identifier value, but in actual it should be test identifier = test identfier (like p1 and p2) and test1 identifier <> test 1 identifier (like in P1 and P2). The question is straightforward. I dont know what is causing the confusion here :)

Comment: Ok. for the given sample data, with identifier ='test', parent 1 and parent2 have same identifier value but with identifier='test1'  value for both parent 1 and 2 are different.

Comment: or can you add one more records for each parent in child table with value 'test' and 'test1' and show the expected results

Comment: would need expected result after adding the data *insert into child_table
select 1 as parent_id, 'test' as Identifier, '<some other value>' as Identifier_value from dual
union
select 1 as parent_id, 'test1' as Identifier, '<some other value>' as Identifier_value from dual
union
select 2 as parent_id, 'test' as Identifier, '<some other value>' as Identifier_value from dual
union
select 2 as parent_id, 'test1' as Identifier, '<some other value>' as Identifier_value from dual*